# How can I add an element to an IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have the following code:

```
      var contentTypes =
          (
              from contentType in this._contentTypeService.GetContentTypes()
              select new
              {
                  id = contentType.ContentTypeId,
                  name = contentType.Name
              }
          );
```

How can I add another element to contentTypes with an id of 99 and a name of "All"?

I was trying to use contentTypes.Add(

but that does not seem to be allowed with intellisense.

Comment: You can convert contentTypes to List and then invoke Add method on it.

Comment: Gemma, you should check for existing Q&A before posting a new question. This has been asked multiple times on StackOverflow, using virtually the same title you used for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add to an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx). `IEnumerable<T>`s represent sequences that you can iterate over; they do not represent a collection that you can add to. What you can do is [concatenate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) to the end of your sequence though, obtaining a new sequence:

```
var sequence = contentTypes.Concat(
                   new[] {
                       new { id = 99, name = "All" }
                   }
               );
```

Now, if you iterate over `sequence`, you'll first see the elements of `contentTypes` streamed to you, and then the final item will be the appended item `new { id = 99, name = "All" }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your new values to the end of the IEnumerable<>.

```
var contentTypes =
   (
      from contentType in new[]{new {ContentTypeId = 1, Name="TEST"}}
      select new
      {
          id = contentType.ContentTypeId,
          name = contentType.Name
      }
   ).Concat(new[]{new {id = 99, name="All"}});
```

The resulting IEnumerable will end with 99/All

Answer (score 0):

If you use `contentTypes.ToList()` you can then add to that list, however doing so will create a new instance of a collection, so your not actually modifying the source collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var contentTypes =
          (
              from contentType in this._contentTypeService.GetContentTypes()
              select new
              {
                  id = contentType.ContentTypeId,
                  name = contentType.Name
              }
          ).ToList();
```

As you have converted contentTypes to a List, it should allow you to add a new item to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use `IList.Add` on an `IEnumerable<T>`.  So you need to create a new collection.

You are selecting an anonymous type, use `Concat` to add a fixed anynymous type to your query:

```
var allTypes = new[]{new { id = 99, name = "All" }};    // creates a fixed anonymous type as `IEnumerable<T>`
var contentTypes = from contentType in this._contentTypeService.GetContentTypes()
                   select new
                   {
                       id = contentType.ContentTypeId,
                       name = contentType.Name
                   };
var result = allTypes.Concat(contentTypes).ToList(); // concat
```